# Process startinfo.filename Indicar Ruta de acceso a un archivo dentro de una red

Tags: vb.net

estoy abriendo unos archivos, pero estos no están en la misma PC, si no que están en otro servidor, en mi pc funciona muy bien, pero cuando pongo la ruta de otra PC que esta en la red me indica un error,

como podría  indicar una ruta en la red??
[image: ruta en una red]

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega tu codigo real, no una imagen del mismo. Tambien por favor lee los links que te pase, y aclara cual es el error que estas recibiendo. Puede que no tengas acceso a esa carpeta? es raro que el link tenga una direccion y despues incluya c:\

Comment: Si la carpeta está en otro equipo, debes compartir esa carpeta en la red para que puedas acceder.